# Manuals for a Cahn TG-171 Thermogravimetric Analyzer

Tags: analytical-chemistry

[image]Recently a Cahn TG-171 Thermogravimetric Analyzer was donated to my school. We did not get a service or user's manual with it, and some of it still needs to be put back together.

I have tried to contact Thermo Fisher who bought Cahn Instruments, but they no longer support the TG-171. Any sort of information on the setup of this instrument would be appreciated.

**Update:**
In particular, one of the main questions I now have is "what must I do to use the balance?" Currently there are eccentric screws (as shown in the photo) preventing the balance beam from moving so it is unable to register mass change. Do I loosen both sets and use a counterweight of a calibrated mass? Is there a common procedure for setting up balances of this type?

Comment: I asked about this on meta, but I didn't think I got a conclusive answer about whether it was on topic. http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/1682/4813

Comment: although not really an answer, have you tried contacting a local university or possibly even the donor? It's possible that someone who works with these instruments (maybe not this model) maybe able to work out the details of your particular model.

Comment: Ask the material sciences department in [Leuven](https://www.mtm.kuleuven.be/equipment/thermal-analysis/thermo-gravimetrical-analysis), who have this instrument.